# Demo-Docusign Connect Notifications not working

Tags: docusignapi

We recently noticed that the connect notifications stopped working. We do have [DocuSign Connect Settings](https://demo.docusign.net/Member/MemberEnvelopeIntegration.aspx) enabled to post back to our server when an Envelope is singed/completed.
The last successful one was received on May 22nd 2018 and I don't see any failures.

Can someone look into it and advise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have `Require Acknowledgement` enabled in your Connection setting? DocuSign only moves anything to failure queue if `Require Acknowledgement` is checked and it did not receive any response from the configure listener url.

Answer (score 0):

For this you might want to open a case with DocuSign Support and provide them the Demo Account ID. There's most likely an error your server is returning and if Require Acknowledgement is off it won't be logged on the DocuSign side.

Answer (score 0):

What software stack does your server (your "listener") use?

Only TLS 1.1 or better is currently allowed by DocuSign Connect.

See the [support article](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/End-of-TLS-1-0-and-weak-cipher-support). Does your server support TLS 1.1 or 1.2?